# Word to text :: Numbered Bullets gets deleted

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a .docx file where I have numbered bullets. An example will be:

```
1. Main Topic
1.1 Sub Topic 
     Facts on Sub topic
1.2 Sub Topic 1
     Facts on Sub Topic 2
2. Another main topic
2.1 random text
2.2 random text1
```

**My Code:**

```
import os
import docx2txt
text=""
path = ("my_file.docx")

text=docx2txt.process(path)
```

I am getting the value of `text` like this:

```
Main Topic
Sub Topic 
     Facts on Sub topic
Sub Topic 1
     Facts on Sub Topic 2
Another main topic
random text
random text1
```

**Problem**:

The output is correct, all I need is that numbered bullets should also be in the output.

Am I missing something here to get the desired output

Comment: The numbers in the bullets are not actually part of the text in Word. Word generates them on the fly. That is why they change if you insert an item into the middle of a list. So they are not really in your input, and so you will have to provide them yourself in the output.

Comment: @BoarGules: So, there is absolutely no way I can get the numbered bullets in the output ?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you are going to have to put them there yourself in your own code.

Comment: Something like on every line change increment a number or so!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `python-docx` and `python-pptx`? Bullets are not actually part of the text content in most rich-text editors like Word, so they're a little harder to extract. However, in `python-pptx` you can access `Paragraph.text` for a plaintext string or `Paragraph.style` for the List Bullet style.

I haven't fully dug into it but there's a lot of documentation for `Paragraph` here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html

In addition, it looks like this is a requested feature:
https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/100

Comment: I have tried extracting paragraph by paragraph also, but ended up in same place :(

Comment: Yes, but unlike `docx2txt` which concentrates exclusively on the text, `python-docx` will also tell you something about the paragraph format, and you can probably use that to deduce what kind of paragraph it is, and how it needs to be numbered by your code, since paragraphs of the same kind tend to get successive numbers.

Answer (score -1):

How particular are you about your numbering? `docx2python` will return this list as.

```
1) Main Topic
    1) Sub Topic 
Facts on subtopic
    2) Sub Topic 1
Facts on Sub Topic 2
2) Another main topic
    1) random text
    2) random text1
```

It's not your exact input, but you could pretty easily hack it back in to what you wanted. The indentation and number values would be there.

If you'd just like to see the text as above:

```
from docx2python import docx2python

print(docx2python('document.docx').text)
```

The numbered lists will be indented with tabs, you could count the tabs and write a little parser starting with

```
from docx2python import docx2python
from docx2python.iterators import iter_paragraphs

content = docx2python('document.docx')
paragraphs = list(iter_paragraphs(content.document))
```

That will put all the header, footer, content, footnote, and endnote text into a list. You could select any part of that by using

```
content.header
content.footer
content.body
content.footnotes
content.endnotes
```

instead of `content.document`.

One issue with exporting docx, html, pdf, etc. to plain text is that plain text has no way to indent paragraphs. You can indent *the first line* of a paragraph with spaces or tabs, but the rest of the paragraph won't be indented.

```
        My plain-text, tab-indented paragraph will only be indented before
the line wrap, after that...
```

You've got to 1) stay with the original format or 2) accept some serious compromises.

Best of luck on your project.

Comment: Can you write a sample code on how to use `docx2python`

Comment: I think going into the document and changing the list is going around the programming problem.